# Installing Ubuntu on Mac using Bootcamp

Tags: system-installation, mac, bootcamp

Am currently running Ubuntu 11.10 on Mac using Parallels. Its only 2 days that am using Ubuntu, am quite impresses with the OS features. Am now planning to install the OS using bootcamp in Mac. I would like to know more about the following

1. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on Mac using bootcamp.
2. If Yes(#1), can I install using the ISO file or do I need setup CD for the same.
3. Whats the ideal configuration required to install Ubuntu 11.10 (HDD space, Memory)
4. After installation, how do I connect to internet.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would keep using it as a virtual machine until you get more confident within the OS.

A longer but easier/safer method of installation is to install Bootcamp then Windows, then use the Ubuntu installer in windows to share the Bootcamp space. You could also then delete the windows data and reclaim the space.

Here is a guide after getting windows into to install ubuntu:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-dual-boot-windows-and-linux-with-wubi-installer/
Its for an older version but should still apply

If you want to go the true dual boot method on OSX, read up:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation
AND BACKUP, especially when messing with EFI

Comment: Whats the minimum disk space required by Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Desktop version is 5GB, server is 1GB.

Answer (score 0):

Bootcamp is only suitable when installing Windows 10 etc.on the Intel Apple Mac, Linux/Ubuntu {22.04 (Jellyfish) or 23.04 (Lobster)} is best installed by partitioning using disk utility on the e.g. 2014 and, or 2018 Mac Mini & then using a Rufus prepared [I do this on a Windows machine] flash drive installer e.g. 16GB.

Answer (score -1):

You can just install the Ubuntu 11.10 ISO file and burn it to a USB drive and then reboot and install Ubuntu through the partitioning option.

Comment: You should be saying Ubuntu 12.04 or 13.04, not 11.10 which is not supported anymore.